# Outlook prompts the user when performing a Save As on a digitally signed/encrypted message

Tags: c#, windows, service, outlook

When saving (Save As) a digitally signed message Outlook prompts the user with a message box question "You are about to save a digitally signed email message in a format which is not secure. Do you want to continue?".

I need Outlook to save the message without displaying the message box.  Is there ANY way to suppress this message, via Outlook settings, registry entries, or programmatically?

One other complication is that Outlook is being executed via a service.  I can successfully programmatically respond to the message box is various ways but none of them work when running as a service.  SendKeys, SendMessage, PostMessage and SendInput all work when running on the desktop, but fail when running as a service.

```
            Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").FirstOrDefault();
            if (p != null)
            {
                IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
                SetForegroundWindow(h);
                // SendKeys works when running on the desktop, but not when running as a service.
                SendKeys.SendWait("y");
                // SendMessage works when running on the desktop, but not when running as a service.
                SendMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x59, 0);
                // PostMessage works when running on the desktop, but not when running as a service.
                PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x59, 0);
                // SendInput works when running on the desktop, but not when running as a service.
                Input[] inputs = new Input[]
                {
                    new Input
                    {
                        type = (int)InputType.Keyboard,
                        u = new InputUnion
                        {
                            ki = new KeyboardInput
                            {
                                wVk = 0,
                                wScan = 0x15, // Y
                                dwFlags = (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyDown | KeyEventF.Scancode),
                                dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Input
                    {
                        type = (int)InputType.Keyboard,
                        u = new InputUnion
                        {
                            ki = new KeyboardInput
                            {
                                wVk = 0,
                                wScan = 0x15, // Y
                                dwFlags = (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyUp | KeyEventF.Scancode),
                                dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
            }
```

Is the a way to suppress or respond to the dialog?  Could an Outlook add-in detect the dialog and dismiss it?

Answer (score 0):

That prompt for signed/encrypted messages is only shown if you are accessing OOM from outside of the outlook.exe address space. `Outlook.Application` object furnished to Outlook VBA or COM/VSTO addins is trusted and does not show that prompt.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), Redemption won't show any prompts: you can reopen the message using `GetMessageFromId` or `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject`. Note that for signed/encrypted messages the result will be different - since OOM tries very hard to represent all signed/encrypted messages as regular mail items, `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` would produce an unsigned/decrypted message, while `GetMessageFromId` deals with the message as it is stored in the parent message store, and the resulting MSG file would store the message in its original form  - signed/encrypted. Off the top of my head (in VBA):

```vb
set Application = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.16")
set item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
'item.SaveAs "c:\temp\signed.msg", olMsgUnicode

set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT

set rItem = rSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(item)
rItem.SaveAs "c:\temp\unsigned.msg", olMsgUnicode

set rItem = rSession.GetMessageFromID(item.EntryID)
rItem.SaveAs "c:\temp\signed.msg", olMsgUnicode
```